How do I tell which browser tab is focused?
When using Microsoft Playwright, how do I tell which browser tab is focused?
I expected to find a Context.Pages.Current or Context.CurrentPage property, but have not found anything like that.

A page doesn't need to be a tab. The docu says something like "Each page behaves like a focused, active page. Bringing the page to front is not required." So for what playwright tries todo they seem to not need that info of current/focused etc.

Why do you need to know this? It's important to provide context to avoid an XY problem, since this isn't usually something you need to worry about.

I build tools that help users backup their data from web-based applications that have no documented API.  Our tools launch a Playwright-controlled browser that the user logs into.  We then capture cookies/session tokens and use that to communicatee with the undocumented APIs to help the customer get their data.
Some apps launch another tab when you click "login" so I'm interested in knowing what tab the UI shows at the current tab that way I can parse Page-specific values from the tab the user is in.

There's no such thing as a focused tab/page because each page is active. Focusing only applies to debugging, which is why bringToFront exists.
See https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/pages#multiple-pages
